# Pandas Equivalent of Excel Concatanation for Column Values - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, calculated-columns

I have a pandas data frames `df` like this,

```
    A           length
0   648702831   9
1    26533315   8
2   366073121   9
3   354701058   9
4    05708239   8
5   705542215   9
6     1574512   7
7   397015500   9
```

Now, I need to check `length` column and create a new column based on conditions. If `length` = 9, I need first five of `A`, if `length` = 8, I need "0" & first four characters of `A` so on so forth. For `length` 8, I need to add a "0" in front.

For example,

```
for i in df['length']:
    if i == 9:
       df['new_column'] = df['A'].astype(str).str[0:5]  # to take 5 characters for a df with 10000 rows takes a lot of time
    elif i == 8:
       df['new_column'] = "0" & df['A'].astype(str).str[0:4] ## Need help here
```

My Desired out put:

```
            A       length      new_column
    0   648702831   9           64870
    1    26533315   8           02653
    2   366073121   9           36607
    3   354701058   9           35470
    4    05708239   8           00570
    5   705542215   9           70554
    6     1574512   7           00157
    7   397015500   9           39701
```

In excel `power-query`,

it is done something like this,

```
if Text.Length([length]) = 8
   then "0" & Text.Start([length],4)
```

How can I do this in python 3?

Comment: Do you actually need to do anything with the length... doesn't `df.A.astype(str).str[:5].str.zfill(5)`... do what you want?

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the comment. The reason I did length was I wanted to measure length of column `A` and then wanted to bring in characters of `A` based on length. So, yes, I need the length.

Comment: Sure, if you're doing some conditional checks and want to do different things based on the length... otherwise, if you're just trying to pad things with leading zeros - you don't really need it is all I'm saying...

Comment: @JonClements yes. you're correct. As commented in "W-B"'s answer, if length is 5, 4 or 3 then also, I should be able to manipulate the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pad` from the `str` accessor:

```
df['A'].astype(str).str.pad(5, side='left', fillchar='0').str[:5]

0    64870
1    02653
2    36607
3    35470
4    00570
5    70554
6    00157
7    39701
```

Comment: If one wanted... could also do this as: `df['A'].astype(str).map('{:0>5.5}'.format)`...

Answer (score 2):

IIUC using `zfill` with string slice

```
[x[:5-9+y].zfill(5) for x,y in zip(df.A.astype(str),df.length)]
Out[356]: ['64870', '02653', '36607', '35470', '05708', '70554', '00157', '39701']
```

Comment: I am finding a little difficult to understand your code. I see it is a list comprehension. Also, will this allow me to manipulate the code, such as if length = 5, then do nothing and length =4 then add a "0" infront?

Comment: @user9431057 in the list 5-(9-y) is how many character you will select from the string based on your question